# I want to have a swap size equal to the machine RAM (memory)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, memory

I already wrote some of the code:

```
echo " > Get MemTotal"
export MEM_TOTAL=`echo "scale=0; ($(awk '/MemTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo) / 1000) + 1" | bc 2>/dev/null`

echo " > Set new swap memory"
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=${MEM_TOTAL}M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

I am just unsure about where to put the `${MEM_TOTAL}` variable. Everything else has been tested and works.

So in other words, am I doing this right, if my goal is to have a swap equal to the size of my memory?

Comment: Why? Why not 2* physical ram? or 4?

Comment: I am unsure I understand your question. I think the command `$(awk '/MemTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)` gets the total memory. Unless I am wrong.

Comment: This is not related to stackoverflow. It should be moved to *Server Fault* or Ask Ubunto...

Comment: Read better, this is pretty related to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you obtain the value of total memory in [*megabytes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) but you are using `M` which means [*mebibytes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) for sed. That's a difference.

You need to use `MB` to tell sed that the block size is in megabytes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1MB count="${MEM_TOTAL}"
```

---

However, you can also use the `truncate` command, that's much faster:

```
truncate -s "${MEM_TOTAL}"MB /var/swap.1
```

Furthermore you can use the `free` command to obtain the amount of memory in megabytes:

```
MEM_TOTAL="$(free -m --si | awk 'NR==2{print $2}')"
```

That's probably less hackish.

But at the end you could even just use the byte value from `/proc/meminfo` and pass that to `truncate`, no calculation needed:

```
truncate -s "$(awk '/MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo)" /var/swap.1
```

(Don't use bytes and a `bs=1` with `dd`. That performs very slow. Use `truncate`)

Comment: I appreciate the truncate. There's no need of zeroing out the swap space before use.

Comment: If the file does not exist already it *will* be filled with zero bytes by `truncate`

Comment: My man page says "the extended part (hole) reads as zero bytes". I am not sure, but it sounds different than "filled with zeros". Sparse file? Anyway, if the file is enlarged, using truncate avoids to write zeros in the already existing part.

Comment: Yes. If you want be sure that the file is completely zeroed remove it before `truncate`

Comment: My point was exactly that: "there is no need to clear swap space before using it", so why uselessly zero it?

Comment: You talked about two things: You said (1) that `truncate` won't zero the extended range of bytes. That's not true. You said (2) that it isn't necessary that a swapfile get's zeroed. That's true.

Comment: So I don't need `sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1` and `sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1`? Because that's what I found online: http://www.the-tech-tutorial.com/adding-swap-to-any-ec2-instance/

Comment: Also isn't MemTotal in KB?

Comment: Sure you need the the mkswap and swapon commands. I didn't exactly looked at how you calculated MemTotal. It's just obvious that you divide by 1000 instead of 1024. Use the last `truncate` command I've posted and after that mkswap and swapon.

Comment: Is this ok:
`truncate -s "${MEM_TOTAL}" /var/swap.1 &&
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1 &&
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1`

Comment: The original value: `MemTotal:        1017812 kB` I got it from: `cat /proc/meminfo`. So dividing it by 1000 was the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

`MEM_TOTAL` is roughly in megabytes, so you should use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=$MEM_TOTAL
```

Your code tries to allocate and write gigabytes of RAM a thousand times over. In general, `bs` (the block size) should be your constant base unit, and only the count should every vary.